# How to set AvoidCallingFinalize in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache, apache-camel

The source code of apache camel has a file camel-pmd-ruleset.xml. What does this file actually do. It has a line commented out

```
     <!--<rule ref="rulesets/finalizers.xml/AvoidCallingFinalize"/>-->
```

However I dont have any such xml in my Application. How to I set AvoidCallingFinalize while running my code. Is there a property that I can set which does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is part of some PMD rules which are used if you setup eclipse using the mvn eclipse:eclipse command. Its not used at all for running Camel.

Its only used for Camel committers whom want to work on the Camel source code from eclipse, to have their eclipse project setup so the source code is formatted / accordingly to the source code standard the project uses.